# Android: Thread creating another instance of Singleton

Tags: java, android, singleton, android-10.0

I have a `singleton` object in my app.

```
public class Single {

    private Context mContext;
    private static Single sInstance;

    public synchronized static Single getInstance(Context context) {
        if(sInstance == null) {
            sInstance = new Single(context);
        }
        return sInstance;
    }

    private Single(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }
}
```

When I run my app, I create instance of this class by calling `getInstance` method on main thread. But when I call `getInstance` method from separate thread in same process, it creates another instance of `Single` class.

Shouldn't my code have only one object of `Single` class per process? How can I change it to have single instance per process.

What I am doing is:

```
private class ProfileBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        Log.v(TAG, "onReceive :: " + action);
        Handler handler = mHandlerMap.get(action);
        if (handler != null) {
            handler.onReceive(context, intent, device);
        }
    }
}

interface Handler {
    void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent, BluetoothDevice device);
}

private void registerIntentReceiver(BroadcastReceiver receiver, IntentFilter filter) {       
    mContext.registerReceiver(receiver, filter, null, mReceiverHandler);      
}
```

I am registering my `ProfileBroadcastReceiver` in `registerIntentReceiver` method. I am also passing an `android.os.Handler` object so that `onReceive` method runs on separate thread.  This is where I call `getInstance()` method:

```
private class StateChangedHandler implements EventManager.Handler {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent, BluetoothDevice device) {
        ..
        Single single = Single.getInstance(context);
        .
        .
    }

}
```

Comment: How did you verify that it wasn't returning the same instance?

Comment: I added logs in its constructor and checked. I also checked using toString() method. I am getting new instance.

Comment: Did you try to make the `sInstance` [volatile](https://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_volatile_when.shtml)?

Comment: Please confirm is this issue only happen on Android 10? and could you please show your code to create instance of this Singleton, one in main thread, and another one in background thread.

Comment: yes, it only happens in Android 10. I added more code.

Comment: @Floern I tried volatile , it did not help

Comment: Finally solved it. It was a silly mistake. Somewhere in code it was being set null. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid Memory leak you have to remove the `context` field from the `Single` class. This code works fine in my project.

Comment: can you please explain more.

Comment: `Context` object will be alive even after activity gets destroyed which leads to memory leak, you shouldn't maintain `activity`,`context` and `view` fields in static class. You have to use `WeakReference` if you want context in static class.